# Different fontsizes for different x tick labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'd like to have tick labels of varying size, perhaps by passing a list of fontsizes.

The following is a minimal example of what I'd like to do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,4,9]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks([1,2,3],
           labels = ['one','two','three'],
           fontsize=['x-large','large','medium'],
          )
```

It becomes a working example if you comment out the penultimate line starting `fontsize`, but of course all the x tick labels are the same size.

If anyone's wondering why I want this, it's because I'd like to make 'Ku' and 'Ka' bigger than 'VV' and 'HH' in the following figure:

[image]

To make the figure I'm calling:

```
xticklabels = ['HH','\n\nKu', 'VV', 'HH', '\n\nKa', 'VV']
ax.set_xticklabels(xticklabels, fontsize='x-large')
```

But I would of course like to pass a list to the `fontsize` argument.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It'll be easier for you to use major ticks for `Ku, Ka` and minor ticks for `HH, VV`:

```
x = [0.6, 1.4, 2.6,3.4]
y = [1,2, 2,1]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x,y, edgecolor='k')
ax.set_xticks([1,3])
ax.set_xticklabels(['\nKu','\nKa'], fontsize='x-large')
ax.set_xticks(x,  minor=True)
ax.set_xticklabels(['HH','VV','HH','VV'],fontsize='small', minor=True)
```

Output:

[image]